# OutOfMemoryException error for bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I am getting a `System.OutOfMemoryException` when I try storing a portions of an image to a bitmap using a loop. I do not think it's because the image is too big because another version of my code uses multiple of the same image but without a bitmap. Here is what I got:

```
Bitmap map = new Bitmap(img);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        // Clone a portion of the Bitmap object.
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(i*(img.Width / 4), 
                                    y*(img.Height / 4),
                                    img.Width,//image width
                                    img.Height);

        PixelFormat format =  map.PixelFormat;
        Bitmap clone = null;
        try {
            clone = map.Clone(rec, format);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryException e)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your rectangle bounds are not inside the image.

I think you misunderstood the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wcdy991(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Rectangle` It gets upper left corner (first and second parameter) and width and height of the rectangle. When you set upper left corner inside your bitmap and provide `image.Width` and `image.Height` as width and height of the rectangle it will definitely fall outside of bitmap and you will get `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: ohhh okay, thanks! So the first who values would be the x and y position of the top left corner then, if say I wanted to start at the top left corner?